# Find the number of employees that are female, do not have a college degree, and do not have children?

Tags: probability

> There are $1220$ employees in a company. The information given is that $600$ are Male, $610$ College Graduates and $410$ Have Children. Furthermore, $245$ are Female and College Graduates, $180$ are Female and Have No Children, and $240$ Have Children and are Not College Graduates. The last bit of crucial information is that there are $50$ Females that are College Graduates and Have Children.

I know that there are $620$ Females and $245$ of them are College Graduates. So I assume that $620-245 = 375$, representing the number of Females who are Not College Graduates. Likewise I did a similar process to find the number of Females that Have No Children. 620-180 = 440 is the value of Females that Have No Children. I was not really sure what to do with the information about 240 Have Children and are Not College Graduates.

My next assumption was that if there are 245 Females (College Graduates) and 50 Females (College Graduates and Have Children) the difference would equal the number of Females (College Graduates and Have No Children). Similarly, then if there are 180 Females (Have Children) and 50 Females (College Graduates and Have Children) the difference implies the number of Females (Not College Graduates and Have Children). The values respectively are 195 and 130. The question given in the Title is to find the number of Females who are Not College Graduates and Have No Children?

For this last part I thought that the Number of Females (Not College Graduates and Have No Children) added with the Number of Females (Not College Graduates and Have Children) is equivalent to Number of Females (Not College Graduates). I solved for Females (Not College Graduates) above as 375 and Females (Not College Graduates and Have Children) as 130 above also. So the difference of these two values I assume would be the answer to my question as 245.

However, I am concerned that my approach did not utilize the information about the 240 employees that Have Children and are Not College Graduates. I am wondering if my approach is correct?

Comment: Some discrepancy in female that have no children. Is it $180$ or $440$?

Comment: 440 is the Number of Females that Have No Children. And 180 is the Number of Female that Have Children.

Comment: What's with the capitalisation of nouns? In English, we don't capitalise every proper noun, so it should just be "number of females" and "not college graduates".

Answer (score 1):

In the female section:

College Graduate/Have Children $=50$

College Graduate/Have no children $=a$

No College Graduate/Have Children $=b$

No College Graduate/Have no Children $=c$

Now:

$50+a=245\Longrightarrow a=195$

$195+c=440\Longrightarrow c=245$, which is the answer.

(I’m assuming you mistype the number of females having no children because there are some discrepancies if it’s $180$. )

Comment: My bad, first time using this platform. Sorry for confusion. So this problem could be solved without using the information about 240 employees who Have children and are Not College Graduates?

Comment: @actBains415 I think so.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help.

Comment: @actBains415 Let me tell you a fun fact. You have $8$ values given here, using which you can find out any information that you can think of here, such as Male with Children, Male with College degree, anything that you can think of. And this is where rest of the information provided which is not used for this calculation come into play.